# Calculate Time Starting Before and Ending After Midnight In Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I have a table with Sart and Stop time in minutes for ex. (15:00-15:20 or 22:00 - 1:15).
I am using Duration.From([Stop]-[Start]), but I am getting negative times for time stretching overnight. 
Is it possible to calculate the right time passed in PowerQuery regardless if it goes overnight or not?

Any help is appreciated.

Nick.[image]

Comment: Add 1 day if Stop is less than Start.

Comment: Thanks  Buddy... That is what I was looking for.